# Localized UILabel with background

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, uilabel

I have an app in two languages (English and German) and app contains labels with background. In English everything is ok but in German UILabels are to short and text which is in it is shorter with 3 dots. Like:

[image]

Can I add some auto-resize property which resize label to correct size? Last one thing is that I have a lot of labels interface-only. I want to save some time and figure it out in interface. Is it possible or the only way is set `sizeToFit` to labels? Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I customised my label, add localization and set frame with inset. How's simple. But one disadvantage is that I have to set `tag` as key. My solution is:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.tag];
    self.text = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);

    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}];
    CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, strikeWidth + 20, self.frame.size.height)];
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So what you want to do is, set the sizeToFit in the interface.

It is quite easily possible.

Set the AutoShrink Property in Attributes inspector, and it will be equivalent to size to fit.

Further you can even Specify the minimum font size and font scale.

[image: Reference : Side screen screenshot for better understanding]

Comment: Thank you for advice but when I have 3 labels each of them will has different font size or scale. My project manager gonna kill me because it will look absolutely awful :)

Answer (score 1):

Kakshil's answer will work for the case that you're not wanting to resize the label to actually fit the contained text.  It's going to reduce the point size of the text in an attempt to fit the available space.  For truly dynamic text that may be the best option.

On the other hand, if you're wanting to actually resize the label to fit the text then you can call [label sizeToFit] after you change the label text.  Alternatively, you can use sizeThatFits: to use a modified bounds, where you don't want the label to grow too big or too small.